# Assigning variable values on the fly in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below config file : OO_CONF.conf with the below contents:

```
appPackage_name = sqlncli
appPackage_version = 11.3.6538.0
```

Now i want to read these variables inside my shell script. So i want a variable $appPackage_name and it should contain the value: sqlncli

The way i am trying to do this is :

```
while read line; do
  newline=`echo $line | sed -e 's/ //g'`
  expr "$newline"
done < ./OO_CONF.conf

echo "$appPackage_name"
```

But it does not seem to work.

Request some help on this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`declare`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare) built-in in `bash` with `-g` flag to make it globally available,

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=' = ' read -r  key value; do
    declare -g $key="$value"
done <OO_CONF.conf

printf "%s %s\n" "${appPackage_name}" "${appPackage_version}"
```

The idea is to set the `IFS` to `=` so to split the lines in the file to read the key and value pairs and then with `declare` we can create variables on the fly with the below syntax

```
declare -g <var-name>=<variable-value>
```

Comment: `IFS='= '` is same as `IFS=' = '` as `IFS` only splits on single characters